# ExternalInterface.addCallback fails in local environment

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, externalinterface

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698506/actionscripts-externalinterface-addcallback-only-working-locally-not-in-product) would answer my question, but I have applied the following fixes:

.as

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

.html

```
param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

.js

```
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
```

And I am still seeing the `ExternalInterface.addCallback` method fail locally.
It works on a web server, **or in the dev folder**. But not in an arbitrary local folder.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that it has to do with when you SWF finishes loading.  If it finishes fast, like it does locally, it can throw off the order in which your page sets itself up.  There's a chance the swf gets in there and starts making calls before third party JS libraries are loaded, etc.  Try setting up some timeouts in your JS and SWF to ensure that things happen in the right order, and see if that fixes it.  I don't think you need the Security stuff - you'll only need that if your html and your swf come from different domains.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do have a mechanism for the html to wait for the flash player to initialize, I hadn't thought of a problem happening the other way. I suppose in my case its not relevant since the html must there first and there are no external files. I do have an answer now though, which I will post.

Comment: How are you opening the html when it is in the arbitrary folder?

Comment: Just in a browser. Is there any other way to open html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add as a trusted location the folder where your swf/html reside. Right click the Flash Player>Global Settings>Advanced>Trusted Locations.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem occurs when you load the .html page from a `file://` URL (rather than running from a webserver, even localhost). This problem occurs because the Flash Player uses a different [security sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html) for local files.

`ExternalInterface.addCallback` cannot be used in the `file://` sandbox unless you've got a Trusted Location set (as per Tom's answer; this may explain why it works in your dev folder if it is set to be a trusted location). Unfortunately, setting trusted locations can be a royal pain, so I prefer to set up a webserver on localhost to do my testing.

If your end goal is to deploy your html (and js, swf, etc.) to a webserver, then you should only encounter this problem during development (barring other cross-domain issues). But if you plan to distribute without a webserver (say burning the files to a DVD) then this will be a recurring problem.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the folder in which you want to test this, to the security settings here:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: This is also correct but it seems to be the old way now, and SO doesnt seem to understand that there can be more than one correct answer to a question. You'd think a Q&A site would know that.