# Flash AS3: Call javascript function

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to execute external javascript function from the swf using AS3.

In first keyframe in main Scene i put this code:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript:myfunction()"));
ExternalInterface.call("myfunction");
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "123");
```

This is all variants I know to execute javascript function.

In the HTML I have following statement in  tag:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

And my function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
    alert("This function was successfully triggered via the flash movie.");
}
</script>
```

Whole solution does not work. Has anyone idea what this issue occurs?

Comment: what is the error you get from console?smth with security?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I run this swf locally. When I put whole solution on the server accessed by http, the problem does not exists.

[ExternalInterface.addCallback fails in local environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708743/externalinterface-addcallback-fails-in-local-environment)