# flex sandbox error on ExternalInterface

Tags: flash, apache-flex

My Flex application **generates a sanbox error SecurityError: Error #2060:** Violation securtity sanbox :  ExternalInterface file:///C:/Documents and Settings/test/Bureau/FPtest/4.5/flashProspectus.swf cannot access file:///C:/Documents and Settings/test/Bureau/FPtest/4.5/flashProspectus.html.

**1)** this works when I do publish it on the web, does not work when I open the HTML file as file://

**2)** params.allowscriptaccess = "always";

**3)** I tested with c:\flashProspectus.html (to avoid having SPACES in the file path)

**4)** in my flex init, I added: Security.allowDomain('*');

**5)** in my flex init I got

Security.allowDomain('*');

ExternalInterface.addCallback("setPage",setPage); *// this lines generates the problem: if i remove it, everything works fine*

I think I really made everything what I could: so what's the matter ?

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698506/actionscripts-externalinterface-addcallback-only-working-locally-not-in-produc

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running the SWF file from an untrusted local directory.

Add the directory "C:\Documents and Settings\test\Bureau\FPtest\4.5" (or one of its parents) to the local trusted directory list.

Currently where this setting is configured varies, depending on which version of the Flash Player and which browser you are using. The old Flash Player Settings Manager should still work though: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Just add the directories from which you plan to run flash content to the trusted locations list.

There is a similar question/issue here: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html